# java and oracle fractional precision

Tags: java, oracle

I have created table in oracle and tried to insert fractional seconds precision 9  as one of the row eg.

insert into t values(to_timestamp('2011-07-08 10:02:02.**999999777**','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF9'));

it works..
but when I try to use current_timestamp

insert into t values(current_timestamp(9));

08-JUL-11 04.06.58.**603824000** PM. It only provides precision to 6 level. Is there any way to use 9 digit precision using oracle function.
And side by side can java insert  same level of precision?

Comment: You are using the Oracle function properly. The example you show is actually returning the precision to 9 decimals, but the last three numbers are just zeros. Are you getting the same behavior every time you use the current_timestamp function?

Comment: The level of precision you get time is likely to be different on different systems.

Comment: Aaron, i am  getting only microseconds level precision with 10,000 rows insert, that conforms my system windows 7 32 bit only supports microsecond precision as answered by Justin. thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle relies on the operating system clock and different operating systems provide different levels of fractional second precision.  Most Unix operating systems provide 6 digits of subsecond precision (microseconds).  Windows generally only provides 3 (milliseconds).  Oracle can only get 9 digits of precision (nanoseconds) if the underlying operating system clock has that level of accuracy.  And there aren't many operating systems on the market that provide that level of accuracy.